# Does OPenVPN requires two network adapters?

Tags: openvpn

I want to install OpenVPN on my server to accept incoming connections. I have read the moreless clear tutorials but one issue remains unclear: Does OpenVPN needs a second network adapter (say `eth1`) which listens for connections and bridges traffic through `eth0`? Can it be done with a single network adapter?

Comment: The LTS server guide article on [OpenVPN](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openvpn.html) doesn't mention network adapters at all, except for a specific example of bridging two of them. So, in general you only need one. That's how I use it.

Comment: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/257-can-an-openvpn-server-be-set-up-on-a-machine-with-a-single-nic

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a single adapter, however you need to setup multiple configuration files in a linux machine to do so. https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO --> Go down to "Editing the server configuration file"

Comment: So it is possible but recommended to use two?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. It is preference between using one adapter and multiple. If one works for what you want to do, do it.

Comment: Want to make the right choice here. The server runs some databases and services among other things (some of them like *bind* to the outside world) and I´m in doubt if installing OpenVPN will somehow tamper with the rest of the network traffic

Comment: Any looping, or DHCP problems would be catastrophic for a server with a number of clients.  Downside, you might have to reconfigure some ports and protocols. Plus now you have a failover.